# What to put in (c) and (d) (when i didn"t code in this question i still get the output)

Tags: java, area

```
public class Circle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int diameter; // (a) declare variable(s)
        Circle2 c = new Circle2(50); // (b) create a circle with diameter 50

        // (c) call to calculate perimeter 
        //     without putting codes here i still get the
        //     output
        // (d) call to calculate area

        // (e) display area and perimeter of the circle
        System.out.println("Area:" + c.calcArea());

        // (e) display area and perimeter of the circle
        System.out.println("Perimeter:" + c.calcPerimeter());

    }

}

class Circle2 {
    double diameter, radius;

    public Circle2() {
        diameter = 0.0;
        radius = 0.0;
    }

    public Circle2(double cDiameter) {
        // (f) construct a circle with a specified diameter and radius
        diameter = cDiameter;
        radius = diameter / 2;
    }

    public double calcPerimeter() {     
        // (g) calculate perimeter
        return (22 * diameter) / 7; 
    }

    public double calcArea() {
        // (h) calculate area
        return (22 * radius * radius) / 7;      
    }
}
```

This is an exam question which mean i cant add nor change anything. All i can do is to fill in the codes into question (a-h) I have tried many times to call are and perimeter but its not working

Comment: You might want to consider using Math.PI.

Comment: alright will do it but what to fill in c and d bro?

Comment: Do you see `(e)`?  If you can do `(e)` you can do  `(c)` and `(d)`.

Comment: I have tried many times its showing error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- a : you have to declare the variables which will be filled with methods :

  ```
  double perimeter;
  double area;
  ```
- b : correct
- c , d : you will fill the variables with methods :

  ```
  perimeter = c.calcPerimeter();
  area = c.caclArea();
  ```
- e : you have to display them , you did it correct anyway because you've printed directly the values from method but the question wants u to print the variables filled

  ```
  System.out.println("Area:" + area);
  System.out.println("Perimeter:" + perimeter);
  ```
- About Perimeter : you have to use this instead `return Math.PI * 2 * radius`
- About Area : `return Math.PI * radius * radius`

Comment: *This is an exam question*  Which is why I didn't provide the answer.

Comment: @WJS he was doing things right , its just about the format of the answer